# How to add links in wickets

Tags: wicket, hyperlink

In java class i need to add list (E.g. list.getFirstName()) to the Label in wicket and that first name shoulb be a hyper link in the html. Below i have code of java and html 
the html code

```
<tr >
          <a wicket:id="gotoClass"> 
                   <span wicket:id="firstname"></span> 
      </a> 
</tr>
```

the java class

```
Iterator<String> brds = list.iterator();

RepeatingView repeating = new RepeatingView("repeating");
    add(repeating);

      while (brds.hasNext())
       {
     AbstractItem item = new AbstractItem(repeating.newChildId());
                    repeating.add(item);
                    String contact = brds.next();  
                 item.add(new Label("firstname", contact));


    }
```

The above code works for me and i am able to add the label i.e if i have 10 first names in the list i am able to add 10 labels in html.But i try to add the anchor tag in html and

`form.add(new BookmarkablePageLink<String>("firstname", gotoClass.class));` in java

then i get the below exception

Last cause: Unable to find component with id 'firstname' in [ [Component id = formname]]
    Expected: 'formname.firstname'.
    Found with similar names: ''

can anybody help me on this

Regards 
Sharath

Answer (score 0):

The link element must be son of the repeating element (as you did firstly). For example:

```
//...
BookmarkablePageLink<String> link = new BookmarkablePageLink<String>("firstname", gotoClass.class);
item.add(link);

link.add(new Label("firstname", contact));
```